# Load config_dev.yml on my server

Tags: symfony

How can I load config_dev.yml on my server?

I tried to set SYMFONY_ENV: "dev" in my env variable.
but symfony loads parameters of config_prod.yml

for instance:

config_prod.yml

```
parameters:
    api_key: "prod_api" #API_KEY
```

config_dev.yml

```
parameters:
    api_key: "dev_api" #API_KEY
```

config.yml

```
parameters:
    others_param: "xxxx"
```

If I check this param on my server

```
$this->getParameter('api_key')
```

I get prod_api even if I check

```
$this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment()
```

I have Prod.

How can I Have config_dev and dev environment on my server?

Comment: Most likely your Apache or Nginx uses `app.php` as the entry point in your application when you should use `app_dev.php`

Comment: And update the app_dev.php for accepting external connection, by default it rejects all but localhost or 127.0.0.1 ...